# How to display a different model property based on language

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the below:

```
<select class="form-control" ...>    
    <option ng-repeat="m in vm.LocationList" value="{{m.LocationId}}">{{m.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

But based on a model property vm.Language, I want to use

{{m.NameEnglish}}

or

{{m.NameSpanish}}

Is this possible in the view?

Comment: one way or another you need to store `NameEnglish` and `NameSpanish` somewhere. Easiest solution, store all of them (including `Name`) in LocationList. Then you can you can use `ng-switch` to change the language, with default selection as Name

Comment: You only need to change the displayed text of the option? What about a inline conditional operator on the option name? Is this enough? `<option ...>{{vm.language == 'en' ? m.NameEnglish: m.NameSpanish}}</option>`. I could provide a full answer with demo if this could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
$ctrl.fieldName = {eng: 'NameEnglish', esp: 'NameSpanish'}
$ctrl.lang = 'eng'
```

html:

```
{{m[vm.fieldName[vm.lang]}}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.